# How to check if a full path executable is correct in autoconf

Tags: executable, cython, autotools, autoconf

I am writing a macro to check for cython on the system my program is about to be compiled.
i can use AC_PATH_PROG all right to find cython when it is in the path, but if the user want to specifiy it in the configure line like this:

```
./configure CYTHON=/home/user/cythonFoo
```

I just can't find the right way to check for it.

This is not working, it always pass the test whatever the value of CYTHON is:

```
AC_PATH_PROG( CYTHON, $CYTHON,"" )
```

This is kinda working, but not really usable, because it would require me to extract filename and filepath beforehand:

```
AC_PATH_PROG( CYTHON, cythonFoo,"", /home/user/ )
```

So i've wrote my own test, but i think there may be a standard way to do it

```
AC_MSG_CHECKING([Checking Cython path $CYTHON is correct])
AS_IF($CYTHON -V > /dev/null 2>&1, , CYTHON="")
if test -z $CYTHON; then
    AC_MSG_RESULT([ no ])
else
    AC_MSG_RESULT([ yes ])
fi
```

Comment: I have a related problem; maybe should file a new question. I am using Centos which is really old, and it has /usr/bin/Rscript.  I install my own in /global/software/bin/Rscrpt and this path is before /usr/bin in my PATH.  AC_PATH_PROG always return the /usr/bin/Rscript.  On my ubuntu I only have one /usr/bin/Rscript.  I don't want to exclude the default place if it is the only one in the system. My current solution is to set RSCRIPT outside my configure.ac.  Not sure there is a better solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're observing the [expected behavior](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.68/html_node/Generic-Programs.html) of `AC_PATH_PROG`.  If the user sets `CYTHON`, `AC_PATH_PROG` is going to treat it as the cython to use, even if it's bogus.  As the first line of the linked page states

> If you need to check the behavior of a program as well as find out whether it is present, you have to write your own test for it

So what you've done is the "standard way".